# OAuth - incorrect signature

Tags: c#, oauth, linkedin-api

I am using https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console to determine why I am getting a `401 unauthorised` message.

For some reason, the signature produced in my code is not the same as the signature generated on this console. For testing purposes, the `nonce`, `timestamp` and `baseString` in the code have identical values to those used in the console. Yet the signatures still do not match?

I am using the following code to generate a signature:

```
HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();
hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", UrlEncode(), UrlEncode()));
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
```

`UrlEncode()` and `UrlEncode()` are the consumer secret and token secret, respectively, with url encoding applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The logic above was incorrect.

I swapped around the token secret and consumer secret so it was `LinkedinOAuthTokenSecret` & `LinkedinOAuthConsumerSecret` (`{1}{0}`) rather than the other way around.

This created the *correct* key which could be used to make a legal signature.